# Google App Engine contact form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, contact-form

I have a static (HTML/CSS) website hosted as an app on Google App Engine - Python. Everything works fine except that I want to add a contact form. I have found a [great template](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/ajax/contactable-jquery-plugin.html) that I wish to use but found that it needs PHP to work. Is there any way to either get it to work or find a contact form that works with GAE.

I know that using GAE for a static website is not the main use of it but it is free and works very well for what I want it to do (host a single page resume).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [GAE Boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate). In the boilerplate handlers, there is a handler named `ContactHandler` that does what you want to do.

You should study the code of this project in any case, since it provides a lot of good practices for writing code in GAE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how to use forms with `webapp2` and GAE. If the version you have just submits via standard HTTP you should be able to rework this to capture that information.

[Handlingforms](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms)

```
import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
          <html>
            <body>
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need it to be able to send it to an email address (mine). I wondered if there was a working sample code somewhere that did this. Will

Comment: You should be able to do that with just a little extra effort.

Comment: Your question did not mention email addresses by the way.